# How can I stop before reading the next line?

Tags: c

I have to read a file like this:

```
0 ->  1:50  2:30  3:10
1 ->
2 ->  0:10  3:20
3 ->  1:20  2:10  3:30
```

Here's my code:

```
graphs = fopen(argv[2],"r");

  if(graphs==NULL){
    printf("File hostgraphs not found\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  while((err=fscanf(graphs,"%d ->",&num))==1){
    row=num;
    while((err1=fscanf(graphs," %d:%d ",&column,&visits))==2){
      hostgraphs[row*n+column]=visits;
    }
    if(err1!=2)
      break;
    if(err==0){
      printf("Hostgraph out of bounds\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      printf("%d ", hostgraphs[i*n+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

It gives me the following result:

```
0 50 30 10 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

The expected output must be:

```
 0 50 30 10
 0  0  0  0
10  0  0 20
 0 20 10 30
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a whole line, then parse that line by itself.

Comment: are you confusing between `n` and `num`?

Comment: my expected output is:
 0 50 30 10 \n
 0   0   0   0 \n
10  0   0  20 \n
 0 20 10 30 \n

Comment: I recommend reading and processing each line seperately, because that's how your data is organised.  Use [fgets()](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#C)  and then sscanf().

Comment: First time `fscanf` `%d:%d` does not return 2 it brakes the loop and go straight to print values.

Comment: Can you explain the expected output by editing your question?

Comment: yes it brakes because my variable err1 gets the value 1 from the next line and i don't know how to fix it. @LPs

Comment: Can you please explain it more? @JohnMessenger

Comment: You should rethink your approach to this problem. As recommended by @JohnMessenger use `fgets` to get a whole line and then analyze it. In the way you coded it, for me, is unsavable.

Comment: I'd think `getline()` would be a better solution than `fgets()` unless there's a hard restriction on the maximum possible line length that hasn't been stated.  The posted file format does not rule out an arbitrary number values after the `->` characters on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by reading the file, one line at a time, using [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), and then applying the same logic, as you are doing, on each line separately.

In the following code, I first get a single line from the file in `buffer` using [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) method. Then I process that line as a `FILE` pointer `fbuffer` using [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) method, which is used to read a string like a file:

```
graphs = fopen(argv[2],"r");

if(graphs==NULL)
{
   printf("File hostgraphs not found\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char *buffer = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

while(getline(&buffer, &len, graphs) != -1)
{
 FILE * fbuffer = fmemopen(buffer, len, "r");

 while((err=fscanf(fbuffer,"%d -> ",&num))==1)
 {
   row=num;

   while((err1=fscanf(fbuffer," %d:%d ",&column,&visits))==2)
   {
     hostgraphs[row*n+column]=visits;
   }

   if(err1!=2)
   {
     break;
   }

   if(err==0)
   {
     printf("Hostgraph out of bounds\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  }

  free(buffer);
  buffer = NULL;
  len = 0;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", hostgraphs[i*n+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Note:** I have just added code to make your existing code work, without making any changes to your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot about your help!! :)

Comment: @AntoniaAntoniou Glad to help! And welcome to SO. If this, or any other answer, helped you in any sense, you can [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) to show thanks and indicate that the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple: remove the trailing space in the `fscanf` format string in

```
fscanf(graphs," %d:%d ",&column,&visits)
```

It should be simplified as

```
fscanf(graphs,"%d:%d", &column, &visits)
```

Comment: it's not that the problem it does not work i tried it

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` ignores the newline then after read first row, it moves to next row and read `5` and results `1` in `err1`. That is the root-cause. You can add `fseek` to move back and start new sequence as bellow code-snip or simply change the algorithm to another effective one.

```
graphs = fopen(argv[2],"r");
if (!graphs) {
        printf("File hostgraphs not found<%s>\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((err = fscanf(graphs, "%d ->", &num)) == 1) {
        pos = ftell(graphs); // save position

        while((err1 = fscanf(graphs, " %d:%d", &column, &visits)) == 2 ) {
            hostgraphs[num * n + column] = visits;
            pos = ftell(graphs);  // save position
        }

        // seek back to previous one and start new sequence
        fseek ( graphs , pos, SEEK_SET ); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i< n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d ", hostgraphs[i * n + j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you needed a way of locating each `'\n'` without reading the next row value from the file. That is very difficult to do with `fscanf` where you have varying number of elements in each row in your input file.

Another approach is to use `fgets` to read the entire line, and then separate the initial `"row  ->  "` prefix from the data values. If you move the values into a separate values buffer (say `vbuf`), you can then repeatedly loop through the buffer by finding the `space`, advancing to the next `digit` and then using `sscanf` to split the `column` and `visits`.

(you actually don't even need to split the values in `vbuf`, you can simply use a pointer to advance past the `"row  ->  "` text working with the entire line.)

The following example puts those pieces together and parses the values into the correct positions in `hostgraphs`. Look it over and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { COLS = 4, MAXH = 16, MAXC = 64 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "", vbuf[MAXC] = "";
    char *p = NULL, *rfmt = "%d ->  %[^\n]";
    int row, column, visits, hostgraphs[MAXH] = {0};
    size_t i, j, n = 0;
    FILE *graphs = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!graphs) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, graphs))
    {
        *vbuf = 0;  /* initialize vbuf, split %d:%d pars into vbuf */
        if (sscanf (buf, rfmt, &row, vbuf) < 1)
            break;

        if (!*vbuf) { /* check vbuf contians values */
            n++;
            continue;
        }

        /* read 1st pair */
        if (sscanf (vbuf, "%d:%d", &column, &visits) != 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid line format\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        hostgraphs[row*COLS+column] = visits;

        p = vbuf;   /* assign p, parse remaining pairs */
        while ((p = strchr (p, ' ')))   /* find space  */
        {
            while (*p < '0' || '9' < *p) /* find digit */
                p++;

            if (sscanf (p, "%d:%d", &column, &visits) == 2)
                hostgraphs[row*COLS+column] = visits;
        }
        n++;    /* advance row count */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output values */
        printf (" row[%2zu] : ", i);
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf (" %2d", hostgraphs[i * COLS + j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    if (graphs != stdin)
        fclose (graphs);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/hostgraph.txt
0 ->  1:50  2:30  3:10
1 ->
2 ->  0:10  3:20
3 ->  1:20  2:10  3:30
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/hostgraph < ../dat/hostgraph.txt
 row[ 0] :   0 50 30 10
 row[ 1] :   0  0  0  0
 row[ 2] :  10  0  0 20
 row[ 3] :   0 20 10 30
```